# Change UIView's super view with animation in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I have a `VideoView` (it is a child view of `UIView`).

By default, it is added to a `UIView` which is small view in the corner of the screen (I called it `ParrentView1`).

I have a button to zoom out `VideoView`. This button performs an action that removes `VideoView` from `ParentView1` and adds it to a bigger view (called `ParrentView2`).

When I perform the code below, it works but the animation is weird. All I need is a zoom out animation from `ParrentView1` to `ParrentView2`.
Here is my code:

```
VideoView.removeFromSuperview()
ParrentView2.addSubview(VideoView)
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.8, delay: 0,
               usingSpringWithDamping: 1,
               initialSpringVelocity: 1,
               options: .curveEaseOut,
               animations: {

                VideoView.frame = ParrentView2.bounds
}, completion: nil)
```

thanks for helping

Comment: What is weird in animation? Are origins of both parent views aligned?

Comment: @AntonFilimonov it's like switch between 2 parent views without animation. the VideoView size is change immediately and user don't see the animation

Comment: I tried to do almost the same except that replaced view was just a regular `UIView` and it worked as expected (superviews origins were aligned so I didn't have to calculate starting frame). So seems like one of your views performs some layout before you call `UIView.animate`. I'd suggest adding property observers (via `willSet`) for bounds property of your `VideoView` and put a breakpoint there to find out (in stacktrace) what object changes the frame

Comment: @AntonFilimonov thanks, I just test again with fishinear solution and it's work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The likely cause is that when adding it to the other view, it gets assigned a different frame. The solution is to make sure the animation starts at the original location. Something like:

```
CGRect originalRect = ParrentView2.convert(VideoView.frame, from:VideoView.superView);

VideoView.removeFromSuperview()
ParrentView2.addSubview(VideoView)
VideoView.frame = originalRect;
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.8, delay: 0,
               usingSpringWithDamping: 1,
               initialSpringVelocity: 1,
               options: .curveEaseOut,
               animations: {

                VideoView.frame = ParrentView2.bounds
}, completion: nil)
```

An improvement point: note that it is customary in Swift to start variable names with a lower case letter. It gets confusing when they don't.

Comment: thanks, it's work, but my problem now is: by default. I set 'ParrentView2' has clipToBounds because the video maybe oversize the 'ParrentView2'. I must set the clipToBounds value to false when animation begin and true when animation end. It's work but when animation end, the view has a crop effect (immediately).

Comment: @TanPham My first reaction would be that it is completely logical that the view will crop when you set 'clipToBounds' to true - that is the purpose of 'clipToBounds', after all. But you may want to pose that as a new question, explaining in more details what you are trying to achieve, what is happening in reality and showing what code you use to achieve it.

Comment: Thinking about it... It sounds like you just want the view to enlarge when playing the video, and then shrink to its original size when finished. In that case, you don't need to move it to another view. Just make sure the parent view has 'clipsToBound' set to false (all the time), and then simply enlarge/shrink the frame of the subview.